# How to print current class name with logback?

Tags: java, logback, class-hierarchy

The following config

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %C{0}: %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

and the following code

```
package tests;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Runner {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Runner.class);



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Runner().new Parent().hello();
        new Runner().new Child().hello();
    }

    public class Parent {

        public void hello() {
            log.info("Hello from " + getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }

    public class Child extends Parent{

    }
}
```

outputs

```
20:42:13.811 Runner$Parent: Hello from Parent
20:42:13.814 Runner$Parent: Hello from Child
```

which means that `%C{0}` outputs something different, than `this.getClass().getSimpleName()`.

Is it possible to output the same as latter with logback pattern?

Answer (score 7):

In logback config file, use a conversion specifier: **%class{0}** to output the class name. Example:

`<pattern>%d %-5level %class{0}: %msg%n</pattern>`

Else, try using the Logger simple name by `%logger{0}`, and use a desired logger for each class.

Comment: `%class` outputs the name of the class, where the print call is coded, while I need to print current class name, which can be descendant.

Comment: @SuzanCioc you want  "%thread"

Answer (score 4):

the layout configuration page from logback has this stated:

```
%C
```

or

```
%class
```

from: [Layouts](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html)